# Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString returns string,but goes empty when passed in an API post request

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and don't know what approach I am following is right or wrong.What I am trying to do is to pass the value of two edittexts and one spinner to a API post request on a button click and get the required list of tolls from the response from that API created,and populate a recyclerview just below the clicked button.But the API returns a status 500 i.e. validation error telling the three fields are required.Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong in accomplishing that task.
Here is my OneTimePaymentActivity.java

```
public class OneTimePayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private EditText etSource, etDest;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private AppCompatButton payNow;
    private LoginActivity LA;
    private RecyclerView otp_rec_view;
    private ArrayList<OneTimePayModel> oneTimePayModelArrayList;
    private String textFromSpinner, etSourceText, etDestText, spinnerItemText, url = "https://tollsuvidha-api.000webhostapp.com/public/api/users/toll-list";
    private int id;
    private float tollAmtfloat;
    private String tollName, city, tollAmountString;
    OneTimePayModel oneTimePayModel;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private TextView tvFromSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_time_pay);
        etSource = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSource);
        etDest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDest);
        tvFromSpinner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFromSpinner);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarReg);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        oneTimePayModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        otp_rec_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.otp_rec_view);
        otp_rec_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        oneTimePayModel = new OneTimePayModel();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OneTimePayActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Posting data");

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        otp_rec_view.setLayoutManager(llm);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        etSource = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSource);
        etDest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDest);
        payNow = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.paynowButton);
        LA = new LoginActivity();

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.dd_vehicle_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                spinnerItemText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                tvFromSpinner.setText(spinnerItemText);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        payNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                etSourceText = etSource.getText().toString();
                etDestText = etDest.getText().toString();
                textFromSpinner = tvFromSpinner.getText().toString();


                if (!LA.isNetworkAvailable(OneTimePayActivity.this)) {
                    Toast.makeText(OneTimePayActivity.this, "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (etSourceText.equals("") || etDestText.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    sendRequest();
                }
            }

            private void sendRequest() {
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            progressDialog.show();
                            int status = response.getInt("status");
                            if (status == 200) {
                                Toast.makeText(OneTimePayActivity.this, "Payment Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                String message = response.getString("message");
                                JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
                                oneTimePayModelArrayList.clear();
                                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jobj = data.getJSONObject(0);
                                    id = jobj.getInt("id");
                                    tollName = jobj.getString("toll_name");
                                    city = jobj.getString("city");

                                    tollAmountString = jobj.getString(textFromSpinner + "_price");
                                    tollAmtfloat = Float.parseFloat(tollAmountString);

                                    oneTimePayModel.setId(id);
                                    oneTimePayModel.setTollHead(tollName);
                                    oneTimePayModel.setTollLocation(city);
                                    oneTimePayModel.setTollAmount(tollAmtfloat);
                                    oneTimePayModelArrayList.add(oneTimePayModel);
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else if (status == 500) {
                                String message = response.getString("message");
                                Toast.makeText(OneTimePayActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        OneTimePayAdapter adapter = new OneTimePayAdapter(oneTimePayModelArrayList);
                        otp_rec_view.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("source", etSourceText);
                        params.put("destination", etDestText);
                        params.put("vehicle_type", textFromSpinner);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getContext());
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I even tried to debug the app and see the values of the texts passed to the API.But even if the texts passed are non-empty,it always returns a status=500(validation error) instead of status=200(Successful response).
Here is my layout file of the above activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolBarOTP"
        layout="@layout/titlebar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onetimeText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolBarOTP"
        android:text="@string/one_time_payment"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFromSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/onetimeText" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputSource"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textFromSpinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSource"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/source"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputDest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textInputSource">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etDest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/dest"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textInputDest"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/paynowButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/pay_now"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/otp_rec_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/paynowButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the screenshot of the layout of activity_one_time_pay.xml:
[image: 1]

I struggled to find a solution to this for 3 hours,but could not find anything specific.Please tell me a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Take value in String variable and set that variable global for class.
You should try this :

```
String spinnerItemText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Want integer value :

```
Int value=Integer.parseInt(spinnerItemText).
```

Comment: that spinnerItemText variable you pointed out is **already** declared global by me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 ArrayList<String> spinnerData = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dd_vehicle_type));

        spinnerData.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Even I have had the same problem and this worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for suuuuch a late reply, but I got busy somewhere and almost forgot that I had asked a question and wanted a solution for that ASAP.
And thanks a lot for posting such awesome answers to my question.
But I must tell you that I had found a working solution for my problem.

Here are the changes I have done to my code to make it work

OneTimePaymentActivity.java

The only major change I have made in the code are here

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {      <-----------
```

i.e using the StringRequest instead of JsonObjectRequest

and here

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);                         <--------
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OneTimePayActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching data");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

i.e passing stringRequest to RequestQueue above

```
}
```

The rest of the code is same.

If anyone is facing any difficulty understanding the changes I have made in the code, please leave a comment below.

Comment: Please specify (in a few words/sentences) what exactly solved your problem, not only post the entire new solution.

Comment: I found this solution, by thinking, I need a string from the API, not an object, and most of the people have used a StringRequest for that purpose instead of JsonObjectRequest, so this is what solved my problem, changing from JsonObjectRequest to StringRequest